# Linear Layout I can not see Password on page

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-linearlayout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

I can not see Password text on the phone . I can see outside how can ı fix this?
Sorry for eng.

Answer (score 0):

change `android:textColor` value to `#000000`. But better to use `android:hint` instead of `android:text`. You can also change `android:hint` color by `android:hintColor`

Comment: Okay but this not a solution for the password text place I can not see the main page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the text is there but you can't see it because your text color is the same as the background color (which is white)
So, try changing the text color or changing the background color (or use dark mode to see your text).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with color and you have a single theme, you can combine day and night themes. If the user's Android phone was more than 8, only one theme will work.

I think the bad part
android:layout_height="25dp"
It can be difficult to be seen in phones of different sizes

Answer (score 0):

when u wanna use TextView, try this way for me it's always working.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
```

so how you can see u don't need

```
android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
```